# Database Design Correct Practice

Tags: sql, database

I've come across a small issue that probably pretty common, but that I've no idea how to search for. For example, say we have a database with the following tables:

Table of Exams - ExamID, Name

Table of Exam Questions - ExamID, QuestionID, Name

Should I make QuestionIDs be unique? I could make them unique for every ExamID, or I could just make QuestionIDs never repeat. Are there any advantages/disadvantages to doing either? Also, what should the primary keys be in both scenarios?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kind of depends.

There are a *lot* of possibilities with no real "right" and "wrong".

My thoughts would be to probably separate it out into another table, so that the question could be reused across exams

```
Exam
----
ExamId int primary key,
Name varchar(500)

Questions
----
QuestionId int primary key,
Text varchar(500)

ExamQuestions
----
Id int primary key, -- this is optional, i just like "simple" primary keys rather than composite.
ExamId int FK, -- potentially create a unique constraint on examId/questionId
QuestionId int FK, -- potentially create a unique constraint on examId/questionId
questionOrder int -- this would allow a "ordering" of exam questions on a per exam basis.
```

Answer (score 3):

Make ExamId as unique , because An Exam would not repeat again and again, but Question can repeat in the every exam.

Example : Term End Exam 2014 will not happen again in the next year , same question of Normalization may ask again and again.

Answer (score 3):

If a question belongs exclusively to one exam you would make it unique for that exam. If you expect to see the question on different exams then it can't be dependent on the exam for uniqueness, it would get its key values generated independently of the exam.

An example of a case where an ID would be unique only for another entity would be an order/line item relationship, where a customer places an order that can have multiple line items. The line item has no meaning apart from the order that it belongs to, so you could identify the line items by an order id and a line item number that started from 0 for each order.

Answer (score 3):

The important question isn't whether or not question ID should be unique. The important question is, "What are the semantics of the relationship between Exam and Question?" The answer to that tells us what the primary key of the question table should be.

Your Question table has a foreign key relationship with the Exam table that identifies the [one] exam to which a question belongs. It is the *nature* of that relationship that matters.

- A **non-identifying relationship** is one in which the dependent entity (Question, in this case) can exist independently of the related "parent" entity (Table, in this case). One indication of this is whether a Question can be moved from one Exam to another, or if a Question need not belong to an Exam at all. If so, the primary key of the Question table should be simply the question id itself, which should therefore be unique and non-nullable.

  Whether the Exam ID is nullable or not is dependent on the cardinality of the relationship
  from Question to Exam: is it one-to-one (non-nullable) or zero-to-one (nullable).
- An **identifying relationship** is one in which the dependent entity (Question) exists only within the context of the related "parent" entity (Table). If so, the primary key of the Question table should be compound, incorporating the Exam ID (foreign key to the Exam table) as well as the Question ID, with both Exam ID and Question ID non-nullable.

  This constrains the Question ID to be unique within the scope of an Exam ID: whether it is
  unique across the entire table or not doesn't really matter much at this point, since you need
  the Exam ID *and* the Question ID to identify a particular question.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 tables

`Exams - ExamID, Name` to store exam information.

`Exam Questions -  ExamID, QuestionID, Name` to store questions information with a foreign key from `Exams` table

This means that you are trying to represent a `one to many` relationship between `Exams` and `Exam Questions` tables meaning that a `Exam` has many `Questions` but a `Question` belongs to one and only one `Exam`.

If this is correct then make `QuestionIDs`  primary Key in the `Exam Questions` table.

If this is not correct and a `Exam` has many `Questions` and  `Question` belongs to many  `Exams` then it is a `many to many` relationship. In this case you should have another [Junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) for the many to many relationship. This the three tables would be

`Exams - ExamID, Name` to store exam information with `ExamID` as primary key

`Exam Questions - QuestionID, Name` to store questions information with `QuestionID` as primary key

`Exam Questions Relationship -  ExamID, QuestionID` to represent the many to many relationship with a foreign key from `Exams` table and  a foreign key from `Exams Questions` table